# Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose $A$ satisfies the equation $x^3 + 3x^2 - 4 = 0$. Find $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose $A$ satisfies the equation $x^3  + 3x^2 - 4 = 0$. Prove that $A$ is non-singular and find $A^{-1}$.

I can find two different $A$ that satisfy this; $x^3  + 3x^2 - 4=(x-1)(x+2)^2$.  So surely $I$ and $-2I$ are two such $A$. But how do I know that there are not more? Could we not have some $A\ne I, -2I$ such that $(A-I)(A+2I)^2=0$ and if this was the case, wouldn't such an $A$ be singular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption, $A^3+3A^2-4 I=0$. We can rewrite this as
$$A(A^2+3A)=A^3+3A^2=4I.$$
Thus, $A$ is nonsingular with inverse $\frac{1}{4}(A^2+3A)$. (Recall that given matrices $A$ and $B$ having $AB=I$, then we can conclude that $A$ is nonsingular and $B=A^{-1}$.)

Comment: oh wow, thanks!